# Merge two csv files, add a column with a flag value for all matched records

Tags: python, pandas, csv, merge

I've got two csv files with data and I want to match them, and add a column which contains a flag value when they are matched. The first file is the "master" file with all the patients, and the second file contains the documents ids that have been signed.

Contents of file 1:

```
recid  visit   docid
1      arm1    1012
2      arm1    1023
3      arm1    1024
4      arm1    1026
5      arm1    1028
6      arm1    1031
7      arm1    1037
8      arm1    1040
```

Contents of file 2:

```
docid
1023
1024
1028
```

Desired output file:

```
recid  visit   docid  match
1      arm1    1012   
2      arm1    1023   1
3      arm1    1024   1
4      arm1    1026
5      arm1    1028   1
6      arm1    1031
7      arm1    1037
8      arm1    1040
```

Here's the code I've got so far:

```
import pandas as pd

# which file to read
IN_FILE1 = "patients.txt"
IN_FILE2 = "informedconsent.txt"
OUT_FILE = "output_matched.csv"
 
# load data from csv files
df_file1 = pd.read_csv (IN_FILE1, sep = "\t")
df_file2 = pd.read_csv (IN_FILE2, sep = "\t")

# merge on docid
df_merge = df_file1.merge(df_file2, on='docid', how='left')

# flag the matches
if df_merge['docid'].empty:
    df_merge['matched'] = ""
else: 
    df_merge['matched'] = "1"

print(df_merge) #test

# write to file
df_merge.to_csv (OUT_FILE, sep = "\t", index = False, header=True)
```

The problem is obviously that it is merged on the `docid` column so it's never empty. But the second file contains only one column, so no new columns are added, else I could check those new columns or something.

If I change it to `how='inner'` then it works but then I get only the matches, but the result needs to be all the records of the first file, even when they don't match.

When I edit file2 and change the column name to `docid2` and change the code to this:

```
df_merge = df_file1.merge(df_file2, left_on='docid', right_on='docid2', how='left')

if df_merge['docid2'].empty:
    # etc..
```

It adds a `docid2` column which only contains a guid value when there is a match, so that is correct. However the `matched` column still always contains "1".

Any ideas as to how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html?highlight=isin#pandas.Series.isin) + [`astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html?highlight=astype#pandas.Series.astype) + [`replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html?highlight=replace#pandas.Series.replace)

```
df_parent['match'] = df_parent['docid'].isin(df_docid['docid']).astype(int).replace(0, '')
```

Output:

```
  recid visit  docid match
0   1   arm1    1012    
1   2   arm1    1023    1
2   3   arm1    1024    1
3   4   arm1    1026    
4   5   arm1    1028    1
5   6   arm1    1031    
6   7   arm1    1037    
7   8   arm1    1040
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer, the `.isin` was what I was looking for. Although I don't think I would have figured out the needed type-casting.

Answer (score 2):

[`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with indicator:

```
df3 = df1.merge(df2, on='docid', how='left', indicator='match')
```

`df3`:

```
   recid visit  docid      match
0      1  arm1   1012  left_only
1      2  arm1   1023       both
2      3  arm1   1024       both
3      4  arm1   1026  left_only
4      5  arm1   1028       both
5      6  arm1   1031  left_only
6      7  arm1   1037  left_only
7      8  arm1   1040  left_only
```

Then [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) to convert values:

```
df3['match'] = df3['match'].map({'both': 1, 'left_only': ''})
```

`df3`:

```
   recid visit  docid match
0      1  arm1   1012      
1      2  arm1   1023     1
2      3  arm1   1024     1
3      4  arm1   1026      
4      5  arm1   1028     1
5      6  arm1   1031      
6      7  arm1   1037      
7      8  arm1   1040
```

---

OR without `merge` via [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) and [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
df1['match'] = np.where(df1['docid'].isin(df2['docid']), 1, '')
```

`df1`:

```
   recid visit  docid match
0      1  arm1   1012      
1      2  arm1   1023     1
2      3  arm1   1024     1
3      4  arm1   1026      
4      5  arm1   1028     1
5      6  arm1   1031      
6      7  arm1   1037      
7      8  arm1   1040
```

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer, but that final method gives error "NameError: name 'np' is not defined" and when I change `np.` to `df_file1.` then I get "For argument "inplace" expected type bool, received type str."

Comment: `numpy` is a dependent library for `pandas` you'd need to import it `import numpy as np` but if pandas is installed so is `numpy`

Answer (score 0):

You could use `.isin()`:

```
df_file1['match'] = (df_file1['docid'].isin(df_file2['docid'])*1).replace(0,'')

print(df_file1)

   recid visit  docid match
0      1  arm1   1012      
1      2  arm1   1023     1
2      3  arm1   1024     1
3      4  arm1   1026      
4      5  arm1   1028     1
5      6  arm1   1031      
6      7  arm1   1037      
7      8  arm1   1040
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer, there were very many answers and I accepted another one. The `.isin` sounds like the right way to do this.

Comment: @BdR you are very welcome. I understand that you chose one answer of multiple `.isin()`solutions, please note thought that this answer is the most compact and was also the earliest one using .isin. If you chose another because of readability I would understand though. Happy coding!